# Creating Year, Month, Day Folder Python

Tags: python

If the path doesn't exists the code working fine but when year(2021) folder exists it just stops working after the first condition

```
def check_path():
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta  

    dt = datetime.today()
    year = str(dt.year)
    month = str(dt.month)
    day = str(dt.day)
    
    path = os.path.join( year)
        
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)   
        path = os.path.join(path, month)

        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.mkdir(path)      
            path = os.path.join(path, day)
            

            if not os.path.exists(path):
                os.mkdir(path)
```

The final result I want it is //2021//08//26 folders created

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achive

Comment: That's the logic you implemented. Because all of the conditions are nested, you only add the month to the path and check whether or not it exists if the year folder didn't exist.

Comment: Here's a hint: If you create a month directory inside the year directory, the code will stop after the second condition. [Here's a less subtle hint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/nested_if_statements_in_python.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using Path from path lib like this:-

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

t = datetime.today()
basedir = '/Users/andy'

Path(f'{basedir}/{t.year}/{t.month:02d}/{t.day:02d}').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Note: This is for Unix type systems. For Windows adjust path separator appropriately

Answer (score 1):

You used nested conditions... So, Put conditions as below to achieve your desired output:

```
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.mkdir(path)
path = os.path.join(path, month)

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.mkdir(path)
path = os.path.join(path, day)
    
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.mkdir(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

**For linux should work for you:**

```
import os
import time

os.makedirs(f'/folder/root/{time.strftime("/%Y/%m/%d")}', exist_ok=True)
```

**If you want to create folder in file directory path then you can use following code:**

```
import os
import time

current_dir = os.getcwd()

os.makedirs(f'{current_dir}/{time.strftime("/%Y/%m/%d")}', exist_ok=True)
```